# TypeError: matrix[y].push is not a function when trying to create 2d array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array that represents a matrix (256×256), full of zeroes that I will later change with functions. I tried by using for loops and the .push function, but something is wrong and I can't figure out what's happening. Here's my code

```
var matrix = [];

for (x = 0; x < 255; x++) {
   matrix.push([]);
   for (y = 0; y < 255; y++) {
      matrix[y].push([0]);
   }
}
```

What I want this to do, is push an empty array into matrix, fill it with 256 zeroes, and then repeat that 255 more times.

Comment: You mean to do `matrix[x].push` right?

Comment: Well, at the moment you are trying to access `matrix[1]`, it does not exist yet. In the first iteration of the outer loop you add `[]` to `matrix` (i.e. `matrix[0] = []`). The first iteration of the inner loop calls `matrix[0].push`, which is fine. The second iteration calls `matrix[1].push`, which fails since you haven't added a second element to `matrix` yet.

Comment: ugh, yeh I meant matrix[x]. Thanks, post it as anwser so I can upvote if you want. Can't believe it was that obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only pushing in one array then trying to fill in 255 of them. Your code should look more like this (assuming you want 256 zeroes instead of 255)

```js
var matrix = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
  matrix.push([]);
  for (var y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
    matrix[x].push(0);
  }
}
```